# Unclear Copy assignment operator example

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been looking up some C++ stuff on [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/#copy_assignment).

There is the following example regarding a Copy assignment operator:

```
Example5& operator= (const Example5& x) {
  delete ptr;                      // delete currently pointed string
  ptr = new string (x.content());  // allocate space for new string, and copy
  return *this;
}
```

This is clear to me so far, the article however states:

> Or even better, since its string member is not constant, it could re-utilize the same string object:

```
Example5& operator= (const Example5& x) {
  *ptr = x.content();
  return *this;
}
```

I don't understand why this may be desired. Isn't the first example exactly what we want to achieve?: **Copy** assigning the contents. Why "re-utilize the same string object"?

Comment: `x.content()` returns a copy. The article was clearly written without move semantics in mind.

Comment: Reuse of the same object eliminates unneeded memory release and allocation.

Comment: Deleteing object and creating a new one is unneeded overhead, since ptr is not const you can modify its content. You still are copying.

Comment: `using namespace std;` [...] `string* ptr;`. That's enough for me to throw this "tutorial" away.

Comment: @user1963877 It's not "unnecessary overhead". It's leaking memory. But the whole tutorial is garbage anyways.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper how is this leaking memory?

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann Because you're copying memory that's been `new`'d and doesn't get `delete`'d. There's no transfer of ownership.

Comment: All the relevant code of your "problem" should be in the question itself.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper No you are wrong. This code is fine. You merely copy assign `content()` to your already created string. As long as `ptr` is cleaned up in your dtor and the implementation of `std::string` is correct (guess what, unless you use an exotic compiler, this is truer than true) there won't be any memory leak here.

Comment: Very contrived and in my opinion bad example. Along with the other problems mentioned already the first example isn't exception safe at all, if the `new` throws an error the object is left in an invalid state.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Actually my initial confusion originated from not interpreting the `*ptr = x.content();` correctly. I was missing that fact that `content()` actually returns a reference that is then copied over the contents of a (hopefully) allocated `*str`, thus not requiring re-allocation.

Answer (score 6):

That page states:

> [...]the implicit version performs a shallow copy which is suitable for
>   many classes, but not for classes with pointers to objects they handle
>   its storage, as is the case in Example5. In this case, not only the
>   class incurs the risk of deleting the pointed object twice, but the
>   assignment creates memory leaks by not deleting the object pointed by
>   the object before the assignment.

Lets see the code again:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Example5 {
    string* ptr;
  public:
    Example5 (const string& str) : ptr(new string(str)) {}
    ~Example5 () {delete ptr;}
    // copy constructor:
    Example5 (const Example5& x) : ptr(new string(x.content())) {}
    // access content:
    const string& content() const {return *ptr;}
};
```

So the *implicit* version of the copy assignment operator would be equivalent to

```
Example5& operator= (const Example5& x) {
  ptr = x.ptr; // previous value of ptr is lost -> memory leak
  return *this;
}
```

Which create a memory leak because does not deallocate the element pointer by `this.ptr`.
The proposed version deallocate `ptr`then allocate new memory for it. Deallocating and allocating incur extra cost and extra instructions, therefore the second code

```
Example5& operator= (const Example5& x) {
  *ptr = x.content();
  return *this;
}
```

reuse the same (already allocated) memory area of (this->ptr) to store a copy of `*x.ptr`.

Note that since `x.content()` return a copy of the string in `x`, `*ptr = x.content();` will call the `copy assignment operator` of `*ptr` which in thia case is a string.

Comment: OK, but from what I get this is only acceptable when `string* ptr;` is definitely created/allocated during construction of Example5? I guess I was mentally stuck because `*ptr = x.content();` looks like a kind of risky assignment, assuming that `ptr`already exists.

Comment: It looks risky, but actually `x.content()` returns a copy of `*x.ptr` and call the *copy assignment operator* of string. The example enforce the string to be allocated whenever a constructor is called so yes, it works under these circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Java and some other languages, `*prt = x.content()` will copy a string from `x`.
The main benefit is that you do not need to delete and re-alloc the memory for string object pointed by ptr (which is quite expensive operations), but use std:string`s class copy assignment operator. Also string copy assignment operator (for lvalue references) has strong exception guarantee - so if something will happen inside that method - the state of all objects will be valid. And don't forget that there is a big chance (if ptr->length() <= x.content().length()) that no memory allocation/de-allocation will be needed - only characters copying.

Comment: The class should have a string member in the first place, not a pointer to a string.

Comment: @DanielDaranas for what?

Comment: For simplicity. He's using copy semantics anyway. He's basically storing (and owning) a string in the object.

Comment: @DanielDaranas yeah, that would be easier, but it's another question (of design I think).